# cygwin make and packages in PATH

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I'm trying to run Cygwin packages from a command prompt in Windows within a makefile. I manually put the Cygwin packages that I need in separate folder added them to the PATH environment variable. I'm able to execute the packages straight from the command line and they all work as intended, but when I add the bash line to the makefile (example: `rm -f file.o`), it just straight echos it back when I run `make clean` and doesn't execute rm even though it works from the command.

Anyone have an idea as to why it's not working from within the make file?

edit: here is the part of the code

```
.PHONY: clean 
# Other Targets
clean:
    xargs -a rm.txt rm -f
    banner -c @ done
```

Comment: Can you show some code? It seems you've got the right idea, so it's probably just a make syntax thing. I stumble over that sort of thing all the time.

Comment: can you post the meningful part of the Makefile?

Comment: Is `rm.txt` an empty file?

Answer (score 0):

If it runs inside bash, why don't you call "bash.exe -c make"?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code into a Makefile and created 2 more files: rm.txt and silly. Here's a transcript of the session:

```
x003347@D011-62:~/workarea/trials/mk_test> vi Makefile # copied your code
x003347@D011-62:~/workarea/trials/mk_test> touch silly # create empty file
x003347@D011-62:~/workarea/trials/mk_test> vi rm.txt   # contains file to be removed
x003347@D011-62:~/workarea/trials/mk_test> ls
Makefile  rm.txt  silly
x003347@D011-62:~/workarea/trials/mk_test> make
xargs -a rm.txt rm -f
banner -c @ done
make: banner: Command not found
make: *** [clean] Error 127
x003347@D011-62:~/workarea/trials/mk_test> ls
Makefile  rm.txt
x003347@D011-62:~/workarea/trials/mk_test>
```

OK, the banner command didn't work but the rm command did! My rm.txt contains one line with the word "silly".

What I changed in your code was to simply start each command line with a tab rather than 4 spaces. I'm not sure what you have in your Makefile, since it automatically gets converted to spaces when you paste the code here (I just tried). Still, my guess is that you need to make sure you have genuine tab characters in your Makefile at the start of each command.

BTW: I did this on a linux machine, not cygwin, so that might make a difference... though it **shouldn't**.